# Neo4J - Optimizing 3 merge queries into a single query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

**I am trying to make a Cypher query which makes 2 nodes and adds a relationship between them.**

For adding a node I'm checking if the node is existing or not, if existing then I'm simply going ahead and setting a property.

```
// Query 1 for creating or updating node 1

MERGE (Kunal:PERSON)
ON CREATE SET
    Kunal.name = 'Kunal',
    Kunal.type = 'Person',
    Kunal.created = timestamp()
ON MATCH SET
    Kunal.lastUpdated = timestamp()
RETURN Kunal
```

---

```
// Query 2 for creating or updating node 2

MERGE (Bangalore: LOC)
ON CREATE SET
    Bangalore.name = 'Bangalore',
    Bangalore.type = 'Location',
    Bangalore.created = timestamp()
ON MATCH SET
    Bangalore.lastUpdated = timestamp()
RETURN Bangalore
```

---

Likewise I am checking if a relationship exists between the above created nodes, if not exists then creating it else updating its properties.

```
// Query 3 for creating relation or updating it.

MERGE (Kunal: PERSON { name: 'Kunal', type: 'Person' })
MERGE (Bangalore: LOC { name: 'Bangalore', type: 'Location' })
MERGE (Kunal)-[r:LIVES_IN]->(Bangalore)
ON CREATE SET
    r.duration = 36
ON MATCH SET
    r.duration = r.duration + 1 
RETURN *
```

**The problem is these are 3 separate queries which will have 3 database calls when I run it via the Python driver. Is there a way to optimize these queries into a single query.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can concatenate your three queries to one.
In this case you can omit the first and second `MERGE` of your last query, because it is assured by the start of new query already.

```
MERGE (kunal:PERSON {name: ‘Kunal'})
ON CREATE SET
    kunal.type = 'Person',
    kunal.created = timestamp()
ON MATCH SET
    kunal.lastUpdated = timestamp()
MERGE (bangalore:LOC {name: 'Bangalore'})
ON CREATE SET
    bangalore.type = 'Location',
    bangalore.created = timestamp()
ON MATCH SET
    bangalore.lastUpdated = timestamp()
MERGE (kunal)-[r:LIVES_IN]->(bangalore)
ON CREATE SET
    r.duration = 36
ON MATCH SET
    r.duration = r.duration + 1 
RETURN *
```

Comment: You will probably gain a small saving by removing two Python driver calls. I would like to prefer the concatenated query.

Comment: is the query idempotent? Will it have the same result everytime its been executed?

Comment: Yes. The [MERGE documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/getting-started/current/cypher-intro/patterns-in-practice/#cypher-intro-patterns-in-practice-completing-patterns) states: "Whenever we get data from external systems or are not sure if certain information already exists in the graph, we want to be able to express a repeatable (idempotent) update operation. In Cypher MERGE has this function. [...]". So by using `MERGE` you are following the right track.

Comment: Attention, by doing just `MERGE (Kunal:PERSON)`you are asking the neo4j if there is already a node in the DB with the label `PERSON`, not that if the node `PERSON` with the name `Kunal` already exists or not.  You should always use a `MERGE` on a primary key (with an index / unique constraint on it)

Comment: @logisima can you demonstrate with an example, with my answer?

Comment: I adapted my answer accordingly to @logisima absolutely right hint.

Comment: @ThirstForKnowledge so if we create an UUID based on the key that is bound to be unique right?

Comment: You must match a concrete, unique node by filtering like `{name: 'your content'}` or `WHERE id(kunal)=1234` for instance.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee Exactly.