# Neo4J - Merge statement not creating new nodes with a relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

**I have written a query which builds 2 new nodes if it exists then it just updates the properties and added a relationship between them.**

For the first time when I'm creating the nodes and relationship everything is going fine.

```
// This is the first run

MERGE (Kunal:PERSON)
ON CREATE SET
    Kunal.name = 'Kunal',
    Kunal.type = 'Person',
    Kunal.created = timestamp()
ON MATCH SET
    Kunal.lastUpdated = timestamp()
MERGE (Bangalore: LOC)
ON CREATE SET
    Bangalore.name = 'Bangalore',
    Bangalore.type = 'Location',
    Bangalore.created = timestamp()
ON MATCH SET
    Bangalore.lastUpdated = timestamp()
MERGE (Kunal)-[r1:LIVES_IN]->(Bangalore)
RETURN *
```

[image]

Here I'm adding a node **Kunal** (node) who lives in (relation) **Bangalore** (node). Everything is fine for the first time.

---

The next time I'm adding a different node as follows:

```
// Next time

MERGE (John:PERSON)
ON CREATE SET
    John.name = 'John',
    John.type = 'Person',
    John.created = timestamp()
ON MATCH SET
    John.lastUpdated = timestamp()
MERGE (Bangalore: LOC)
ON CREATE SET
    Bangalore.name = 'Bangalore',
    Bangalore.type = 'Location',
    Bangalore.created = timestamp()
ON MATCH SET
    Bangalore.lastUpdated = timestamp()
MERGE (John)-[r1:LIVES_IN]->(Bangalore)
RETURN *
```

I am adding a node **John** who lives in (rel) **Bangalore** (node).

[image]

---

**But the problem here is, its taking the same node value again from the previous merge statement.**

Can anybody explain this?

Also what is the solution for this, if let's say if we are running the above merge queries inside of a loop using the Python Driver.

[Can't find anything on this tho](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/understanding-how-merge-works/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Reason:

The reason lies in your matching pattern of the first and second `MERGE` statement. Because they only test for the existence of `Label` `Person` and `Loc`, but not a concrete node `Person` with the name `Kunal`.

### Idea:

As @logisima already explained in the comments of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53556628/neo4j-optimizing-3-merge-queries-into-a-single-query):

> "You should always use a MERGE on a primary key (with an index / unique
>   constraint on it)".

### Solution:

You should match a concrete, unique node by filtering like `{name: 'your content'}` or `WHERE id(kunal)=1234` for instance.

Comment: The concrete node would be identified by a key property, in your case probably: `name`. Also you don't need the `type` as it's already in the label.